# How to check if file is binary?

Tags: vimscript, binary-file

Is there any way to determine within Vim that the file which I'm editing is either in text or binary format?

For example:

```
vim http://example.com/
```

vs:

```
vim http://cdn.sstatic.net/vi/img/apple-touch-icon.png
```

Something that would return either True or False based on the content of the current file. One [possible scenario](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3211/467) would be, if the file is in gzip format, I'd like to perform uncompression of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most programs (such as `grep`, `git`, `mercurial`, etc.) consider a file to be binary if it contains a NULL byte.

You can check this with Vim like so:

```
fun! IsBinary()
    return !!search('\%u0000', 'wn')
endfun
```

Note that this searches the entire buffer; and won't be very fast for large files. A faster way would be to use the `file` utility:

```
fun! IsBinary2()
    return system('file -ib ' . shellescape(expand('%:p'))) !~# '^text/'
endfun
```

`file` has a list known "magic" patterns it can check against, and will be a lot faster for some files. The downside is that `file` isn't available by default on some systems (Windows, some Linuxes).

It gets the MIME type, so you can do more advanced matching, such as:

```
fun! IsGzip()
    return system('file -ib ' . shellescape(expand('%:p'))) =~# '^application/x-gzip'
endfun
```

> if the file is in gzip format, I'd like to perform uncompression of it.

gzip files pretty much always end in `.gz`; in fact, some `gzip` flavours won't even work if the file *doesn't* end in .gz; with GNU gzip:

```
$ gzip z
$ mv z.gz aaaaa
$ gzip -d aaaaa
gzip: aaaaa: unknown suffix -- ignored
Exit 2
```

So matching the filename with an autocmd would probably be a better solution. In fact, there's already an example of this in the help: [`:help gzip-example`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#gzip-example).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. For gzip uncompression I've added [another one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3211/467), so to it'd be more clearer I think.

Comment: It looks like the `-i` flag is not specified by POSIX for the `file(1)` command. In [Linux and OpenBSD, it's `-i` (lowercase)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/file.1?query=file&sec=1), but in [OS X, it's `-I` (capital)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html). Both versions accept the long form `--mime`, though.

Comment: `text/html` files would get classified incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your mentioned automatic uncompression of ZIP files (and other archive formats) is already built into Vim, cp. `:help pi_zip`. The plugin sets up `:autocmd`s that detect ZIP files based on their file extension (`:au zip` lists them all), not on their contents.

There's no detection built in, because it doesn't make much sense to edit non-text files with a text editor such as Vim. That said, Vim has some support via `:set binary`, and conversion to / from hexdump format via `xxd`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've asked [another question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3211/467) to address that if that's ok, so if you like, you could elaborate further how to uncompress such files with some specific example.